# Can we change Meta data in Manifest file through java code in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, admob, android-manifest

Is there any way to change the meta data in manifest file from java code directly. I am using admobs ids which is connect with firebase and the banners ads and interstial ads ids put on firebase and get to the program now app_id is in manifest file I want to change it from firebase.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot change what is in the manifest.

Comment: There is no way to modify the Manifest File dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information from your manifest file is baked into the Android app at compile/build time. That means that by the time the code of your Android app runs, the manifest file no longer is available.

If you want to create different variants of your manifest file, you'll have to do that from outside the Android app, before building the various apps.

Also see the Android documentation on:

- [Inject build variables into the manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables)
- [Configure build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)